# Shaping Entities (Custom Columns)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My customer has been using ADO.NET and now wants to move to EF.  I'm starting to wonder if his constraints will prevent it.  (Although it is likely my relative newness to EF that is preventing it.)

Here are the constraints:

1. I may not change the database.
2. I must not change too much of the code (only replace the data layer) The big thing here is, almost all his forms have a datagrid that autogenerates the columns (you'll see what I mean in the small sample)
3. (others I am probably forgetting)

He uses SQL to change the column names.  No problem I thought, I will use projection to do the same.  I have written a trivial example to show what is going on.

```
  SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TestConnectionString);
        MyConnection.Open();
        string SQLString = "Select fName as \"First Name\", lName as \"Sur Name\", lName as \"Last Name\", Age from Test";


        SqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLString, MyConnection);
        DataSet MySet = new DataSet("table");
        MyAdapter.Fill(MySet);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = MySet.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        bindingSource1.ResetBindings(true);
```

And here is my code

```
var MyContext = new TestEntities();
var MyQuery = MyContext.Tests.Select(
               test => new 
                       { 
                           FirstName = test.fName, 
                           SurName = test.lName, 
                           LastName = test.lName, 
                           Age = test.Age 
                        });

bindingSource2.DataSource = MyQuery.ToList();
dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
bindingSource2.ResetBindings(true);
```

So far so good.  Not an exact replication of what he does (my columns don't have spaces in them) but he was fine with it.

But then, he makes decisions base on a double click of the data grid.  So he would want to do something like this.

```
 private void dataGridView2_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Test MyTest = bindingSource2.Current as Test;
            if (MyTest.Age > 50)
                MessageBox.Show("You are old!");
        }
```

Projection creates anonymous types, so I can't make that kind of decision here.  (Note that I have to change the code to do this - his current code makes a choice based on data in the datagrid row, but he is now sold on the idea that we need to use classes.)

Is there a way to do this with Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection does not create ONLY anonymous types. You can declare new class:

```
public class TestViewClass
{
     public string FirstName {get;set;}
     public string SurName {get;set;}
     public string LastName {get;set;}
     public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

And make method like this:

```
IQueryable<TestViewClass> GetView()
{
    return MyContext.Tests.Select(t => new TestViewClass
    {
                       FirstName = t.fName, 
                       SurName = t.lName, 
                       LastName = t.lName, 
                       Age = t.Age 
    }; 
}
```

Now you can get TestViewClass object like this:

```
TestViewClass testView = GetView().Where(t => t.Age > 50).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Further more, should you need list of same class, this works as well: List<TestViewClass> tests = GetView().Where(t => t.Age >50).ToList<TestViewClass>();